# No podspec found for `cloud_firestore` in `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this issue after adding cloud_firestore dependency in my pubspec.yaml file.

This is the entire message in the console:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
  Preparing

Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `.symlinks/flutter/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
[!] No podspec found for `cloud_firestore` in `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:14:in `block in fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:85:in `titled_section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/external_sources/path_source.rb:11:in `fetch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:697:in `fetch_external_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:673:in `block (2 levels) in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:672:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:672:in `block in fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:671:in `fetch_external_sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:85:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:154:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:153:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:116:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:41:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.5.3_1/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.5.3_1/libexec/bin/pod:22:in `<main>´


Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/universal-darwin18/rbconfig.rb:215: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777


[!] Automatically assigning platform `ios` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone XR.
```

If I remove the cloud_firestore dependency the app runs regularly.

When adding Firestore to my project I started following all the steps in the Firebase Console, so I do also the step 3: pod init, pod 'Firebase/Core', pod install.
Then by searching other resources online, I read that I should not have done them.
Could this be the cause?

---

Update
As requested, this is my pubspec.yaml. It is very simple

```
name: mobile_app
description: Ti Assisto
version: 0.0.3+5

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: 0.18.1
  rx_command: 2.0.5
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
  device_id: 0.1.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  built_value: "6.1.2"
  built_collection: "4.0.0"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: 0.10.2
  built_value_generator: 6.1.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: "0.6.1"
```

Comment: Please, post also your `pubspec.yaml` file. Btw: I get no error with `cloud_firestore: ^0.8.2+3` in my `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: @shadowsheep I added my pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

I tried your `pubspec.yaml` file starting over with a Flutter Application with Swift support.

```
name: flutter_app_so_53935700
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# Read more about versioning at semver.org.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: 0.18.1
  rx_command: 2.0.5
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 0.8.2+3
  device_id: 0.1.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  built_value: "6.1.2"
  built_collection: "4.0.0"

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: 0.10.2
  built_value_generator: 6.1.2
  flutter_launcher_icons: "0.6.1"


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.io/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And all is fine.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Starting Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           122.0s
```

With a valid `.ios/Runner/GoogleService-Info.plist` I ended up with a running flutter demo application.

Reading again your question, specifically

> step 3: pod init, pod 'Firebase/Core', pod install

It seems that you have also change the `.ios/Podfile` file adding pod 'Firebase/Core' by hand. You don't have to do that.

You can find the right instruction here:

[**Add Firebase to your Flutter app**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup)

You have to stop ad step 2. Anyway try this **codelab** [F*irebase for Flutter*](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#0) that will guide you through the process of adding Cloud Firestore in a Flutter application.

And be aware of that [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25759).

Comment: I read to skip the last steps too late. So I think that I will try to recreate the iOS folder from scratch and see if it work.

Comment: @fabryx92 I know for sure that this will work ;-] Btw, read also the issue I've posted so that you'll be already aware of it. And waiting for your tests, if you wanna support my efforts, upvote ^_^.

Comment: @fabryx92 well, you could also try to simply remore `pod 'Firebase/Core/'` from Podfile and relaunch `pod init` to recreate the workspace. That's should do the work without recreating the project from scratch. Give it a try, before starting over.